# Change the color of 1 cell in every table with Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to change the color of 1 cell in every table with Powerpoint VBA

Right now my code colors every cell in the 1st row of every table. How do I make it color just the cell in row 1 column 2?

```
Sub RecolorTableHeader()
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim x As Long

    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
            If oSh.HasTable Then
                With oSh.Table
                    For x = 1 To .Columns.Count
                        .Cell(1, x).Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Next
                End With
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Just use `.Cell(1, 2).Shape ...` and that will color only row 1 column 2.

Comment: that didn't work unfortunately

Comment: You never assign anything to `x`, therefore it is 0 which gives you an "Invalid Integer" error. The answer of PeterT should work - if not: what happens? How do you call the code? Have you debugged it? Do you get an error?

Comment: It did work for me. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I got it but is it possible to do HEX colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments above, it looks like you were close, but some of your tables did not have a cell at position 1,2 and this was causing your error.

Consider trying the below snippet:

```
Sub RecolorTableHeader()
    Dim oSl As Slide, _
        oSh As Shape

    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
            If oSh.HasTable Then
                With oSh.Table
                    If .Columns.Count >= 2 Then
                        Let .Cell(1, 2).Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rgbRed
                    End If
                End With
            End If
    Next oSh, oSl
End Sub
```

Comment: is it possible using HEX colors?

Comment: @JordanBishop Kinda, and only kinda. I would recommend using `RGB` to input RGB colors. You can try using VBA's builtin hex values (eg `&h00FF00`), but these will break on you frequently, as they like to interpret having any high bits as the number being negative. You can also use the worksheet function `Hex2Dec` as `[Hex2Dec("00FF00")]` or `Application.Hex2Dec("00FF00")`. However, in both of the last two approaches, the order of bytes is BGR not RGB - IE `[Hex2Dec("FF0000")]`  (not `[Hex2Dec("0000FF")]`) will render pure blue